# What does “${x%% *}” mean in sh?

Tags: shell, sh

I just saw "$${x%% *}" in a makefile, which means "${x%% *}" in sh.
Why it is written in this way ?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28994/how-can-a-makefile-detect-whether-a-command-is-available-in-the-local-machine

```
determine_sum = \
        sum=; \
        for x in sha1sum sha1 shasum 'openssl dgst -sha1'; do \
          if type "$${x%% *}" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then sum=$$x; break; fi; \
        done; \
        if [ -z "$$sum" ]; then echo 1>&2 "Unable to find a SHA1 utility"; exit 2; fi

checksums.dat: FORCE
    $(determine_sum); \
    $$sum *.org
```

Also, how to search `${x%% *}` in Google ?

Comment: Google "bash man page"

Comment: Google "how to google bash expression" :) "All CS problems may be solved with yet another level of indirection"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${x%% *}` is a nice way to delete everything but the first word in the `$x` variable. That is, given a text `XXX YYY ZZZ`, this syntax will delete everything after the first space.

Some examples:

```
$ x="aaa abbb"
$ echo ${x%% *}
aaa

$ x="aaa abbb bccc defasdfs"
$ echo ${x%% *}
aaa
```

It is equivalent to:

```
$ x="aaa abbb bccc defasdfs"
$ echo $x | awk '{print $1}'
aaa
```

To make sure it is clear, let's have another example:

```
$ x="aaa abbb_bccc_defasdfs"
$ echo ${x%%_*}
aaa abbb
```

We look for the first `_` character and we delete from that point up to the end.

To see more of these interesting commands, you can check [Reference Cards #String Operations](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22664).

---

Regarding the Google question, yes, these characters are not searchable through their search engine. Instead, I would advise you to use [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/).

For example, [querying ${x%% *}](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%24%7Bx%25%25%20*%7D) there shows a valuable result.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289671/how-to-search-for-dollar-sign-or-exclamation-mark

Comment: @tripleee indeed! I asked that question in fact : ) So updating with this reference.

Answer (score 2):

The `${x%% *}` substitutes the value of `x` variable with the leftmost space and everything to the right of it removed.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

To the second question I have no answer.